# Advanced string replacements in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some strings in a python script, they look like

```
<tag1> thisIsSomeText <otherTag>, <tag1>!
```

I want to parse these lines, and replace every tag by a string from a dictionary.

Assume my dict looks like:

```
tag1: Hello
otherTag: Goodbye
```

Then the output line should look like:

```
Hello thisIsSomeText Goodbye, Hello!
```

As one can see, the tags (and its braces) are replaced. Multiple occurences are possible.

In C, I would search for '<', remember its position, search for the '>', do some ugly string manipulation...
But i guess, Python has better solutions for this.

Maybe Regex? Well, I hope my task is simple enough that I could be solved without regex. But I have no plan how to start in Python. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want a [template engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 4):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) accepts not only string, but also a function as a replacement as the second parameter. The function accepts a match object, and the return value of the function is used a replacement string.

```
>>> import re
>>> mapping = {'tag1': 'Hello', 'otherTag': 'Goodbye'}
>>> re.sub(r'<(\w+)>', lambda m: mapping[m.group(1)],
...        '<tag1> thisIsSomeText <otherTag>, <tag1>!')
'Hello thisIsSomeText Goodbye, Hello!'
```

Comment: @falsetrue: I guess your solution is better than the above. However, i couldn't get it working out of the box. So I ended up with the solution from greato, as this was working (after fixing the known issues).... As I'm writing this, I think i found the issue. Reassigning is also necessary, right?

Comment: @lugge86, Could you explain how my solution does not work? Was there any error? If it had, please share me the traceback.

Comment: @lugge86, Yes, you need reassignment.

Comment: @lugge86, My answer will raise an exception if there's a tag which is not defined in the dictionary. To leave such word as is: use `dict.get` instead of `dict[..]`: `lambda m: mapping.get(m.group(1), m.group(0))` or or `lambda m: mapping.get(m.group(1), m.group(1))` according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in dictionary.keys():
    string.replace('<'+i+'>',dictionary[i]]
```

Comment: You don't need to use `keys` method because itearting dictionary yields keys. You need to assign back the replace string (`str.replace` does not replace the string in-place, but returns a new string)

Comment: If dictionary is like `{'a': 'b', 'b': 'a'}`, this could yield unwanted result.

Comment: @falsetru: No, i think thats no problem. Because, after '<a>' has been replaced by 'b', the braces are gone. So, when searching for '<b>' there wont be any result. Correct me pls if I'm wrong. So far, this solution works for me!

Comment: @lugge86, What if the string is `<<b>>`? And this solution has a syntax error.  And as I commented, the return value of the `str.replace` should be assigned back. Otherwise, the string will be remain same.

Comment: @falsetru: Yes, sure, there is a syntax error in this code, and yes, the string must be assigned back. I forgot to mention this in my comment, but i fixed this issues in my script. So, it works fine. Regarding the <<b>> Problem: yes, this might be a problem. However, I'm using this script for generating C source and header files, using a template file and a excel sheet. As the template is maintained by me (or other developers around), the risk of encountering this issue is very low. Maybe I let the script search for << or >> and then yield a syntax error, or something.